# How to give font range in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to give font range from 14 to 34 when device font increase through accessibility settings, is there any way to do that in SwiftUI?

For now I know the way of `minimumScaleFactor` but I am looking for exact range

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Test string")
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1) //<--Here
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this were a UIView and you were using dynamic type sizes, you could use `minimumContentSizeCategory` and `maximumContentSizeCategory`. See if you can find something equivalent on the SwiftUI side.

Comment: "when device font increase through accessibility settings" Are you referring to the dynamic type settings? How do you expect your range to be used?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, Its through Device accessibility setting, but when it goes extreme high in that case also I want to restrict for size to 34 equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic type doesn't work directly with size ranges. Like matt in the comments said, you can set the range of `DynamicTypeSize`s that the view can take. You can get the current dynamic type size setting with the `Environment` value of [`dynamicTypeSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dynamictypesize). Then you can put this in a view modifier.

```
struct DynamicTypeRange: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.dynamicTypeSize) var size
    
    let min: DynamicTypeSize
    let max: DynamicTypeSize
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if size < min {
            content.dynamicTypeSize(min)
        } else if size > max {
            content.dynamicTypeSize(max)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
.modifier(DynamicTypeRange(min: .small, max: .large))
```

The actual sizes (in points) for each `DynamicTypeSize` can be found in the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/typography#Specifications). Use that to figure out the range you should use.